# set index type in elasticsearch query using java

Tags: java, spring, indexing, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an entity class with only indexName in annotation.

```
@Document(indexName = "person")
public class Person {
...
}
```

I have documents in Person index with different types user,employee with same fields.

I wanted to pass index type at run time using esTemplate. something like below;
setType("employee")

Is it possible to set the index type in spring data elastic search query?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add little more words to explain the problem statement. Did you try something. Any tried sample code would help others to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use query.addTypes(typeName). It works fine for me.